# Can't run python on virtualenv in PowerShell on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, powershell, pip, virtualenv

Python and pip work just fine in PowerShell, but it's different if I run it while activating virtualenv. I got these errors:

```
(<project_name>-env) PS D:\Kerja\HIT\Python Projects\<project_name>\<project_name>-env\Scripts> python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\Python Projects\<project_name>\<project_name>-env\lib\site.py", line 703, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\Python Projects\<project_name>\<project_name>-env\lib\site.py", line 692, in main
    aliasmbcs()
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\Python Projects\<project_name>\<project_name>-env\lib\site.py", line 515, in aliasmbcs
    import locale, codecs
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\Python Projects\<project_name>\<project_name>-env\lib\locale.py", line 17, in <module>
    import functools
ImportError: No module named functools
(<project_name>-env) PS D:\Kerja\HIT\Python Projects\<project_name>\<project_name>-env\Scripts> pip
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

How can I run python and pip successfully in virtualenv while using PowerShell?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer! It turns out when I use virtualenv on PowerShell, it prioritizes using python and pip from the virtualenv over the PATH environment variable.

The python and pip I mentioned before are located on `/<environment_name/Scripts/>` folder, along with `activate` and `deactivate` script. Deleting python.exe and pip.exe or just simply rename it will do.

Please note, it may affect `pip freeze -l`. I am not sure though.